# Echoing Variables In A HTML Tag

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'm trying to make this tag go from 1-100. Something like this.

```
<div style="width:variable%;">
```

But I can't seem to get it down. I'm not really too keen on JS but I've tried a few things in PHP.

```
<div style="width:<?php 
for( $i=1; $i<=100; $i++ ) {
   ob_start();
   echo $i;
   ob_end_clean(); 
   if ($i === 100) {
      echo "100";
   }}
?>
%">
```

And I've tried the

```
sleep();
```

Function between on the count up. I would like to stick with PHP just because I'm more comfortable with it, and I would like to add some knowledge to the bank, but if you have some other form of solving this, I would love to give it a try!

PS. I don't want it to go from 1-100 in like .5 seconds. It's for a loading bar, so I would like it to at least take 2 or 3 seconds.

Alright. Let me elaborate on what I'm trying to do.

```
<div style="width:50%">
<div class="progress progress-striped active">
<div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="45" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:50%">
```

I'm using Bootstrap, and the bottom "style=width:50%" shows how much it is loaded. So in this instance it is loaded 50%. I need it to go from 0% to 100%! Please help!

**UPDATE:** I've realized now why this won't work, and know now why JS or CSS transitions are the ways to resolve this.

Comment: you do realize that PHP executes on the **SERVER**? By the time the html this code generates actually reaches the client and gets parsed/rendered, the connection to the server will have ended and been closed? You can not animate html like this. You need to use javascript on the client side of things.

Comment: @bjb568 I want to but I still haven't solved my issue. I tried your CSS but I could not get it to work.

Comment: @Jade Oh, that's just vendor prefixes. It isn't fully supported yet, so you need to use `-webkit-` and the like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to do this with PHP. To dynamically update the style of that DIV, you'll need to incorporate Javascript.

Check out this example: http://jsfiddle.net/6h74c/3/

```
var start = new Date();
var maxTime = 8300;
var timeoutVal = Math.floor(maxTime/100);
animateUpdate();

function updateProgress(percentage) {
    $('#pbar_innerdiv').css("width", percentage + "%");
    $('#pbar_innertext').text(percentage + "%");
}

function animateUpdate() {
    var now = new Date();
    var timeDiff = now.getTime() - start.getTime();
    var perc = Math.round((timeDiff/maxTime)*10);
console.log(perc);
  if (perc <= 100) {
   updateProgress(perc);
   setTimeout(animateUpdate, timeoutVal);
  }
}
```

Comment: You don't "need to" use JS. Use CSS transitions.

Comment: True, but I'm sure browser support is important: http://caniuse.com/css-transitions

Comment: @bjb568 possible if the transition is supposed to have static speed, etc. If you need real controll over the animation while running, pure CSS isn't a way.

Comment: @Sirago no real need for the timeDiff, if you trust your computer's clock - and don't suspend the JS while the animation is running. You could just count steps, or continue until 100% is reached.

Comment: I feel like this is the right way to go, but I just don't know how to work with it..

Comment: @Johannes animation-timing-function accepts a cubic bezier.

Comment: @Sirago Simple enough, just drop IE support!

Comment: @jadeallencookless Here is a complete HTML file that you can copy/paste and play around with: http://pastebin.com/8Nyux5Ny

Basically, you need jQuery and you need to call the function animateUpdate when you want the progress bar to start. I've done that for the body onLoad. If you want to make it go slower or faster, add or remove time from maxTime.

Comment: @bjb568 if only it were that simple ;)

Comment: @Sirago Ok, fine. Polyfills.

Comment: @bjb568 You still have to know in advance how the animation should look. If really loading anything, you don't.

Comment: @bjb568 I guess.. but we both know JS is the way to go. If he doesn't know it, couldn't hurt to learn a little.

Comment: @JohannesH. I'm assuming he's not really loading anything. If so, he'll still need to use JS+AJAX and have some sort of way of figuring out progress server-side.

Comment: @Sirago JS isn't the way to go. It's the way for OLD IE to go.

Comment: @Johannes Ok, if you are loading AJAX, that's a sperate question. Go post your AJAX answer to AJAX questions.

Comment: @Sirago Yeah most likely you're right and he really isn't. My point is just: while CSS can do animations, it's only an appropriate choice for everything "static", so not a general purpose successor fo using JS.

Comment: @Johannes And I agree.

Answer (score 1):

PHP is executed on the server, BEFORE the contet is sent to the browser. YOu can, of course, output partial content using flush(), but you cannot change anything that has been sent already. So, even if your code would work, you'd still get

```
<div style="width:1234567890101112131415161718192021222324252627...99%">
```

which is most likely not what you want to get ;)

YOu can do thi using Javascript (there is no need to load such huge libraries such as jQUery for such simple task) - or you can append javascript code that modifies the loading bar at the end of your document using PHP. FIrst method doesn#t allow you to controll the result depending on any real data (at least not that easily), second is possible but very ugly and not valid code (so it may not work in all browsers). So: don't.

Proper way to do this if there really is something that loads is to either use flash (which is usually done here) to upload/load/... or to use AJAX calls (which is the most complex way) to determine progress.

If there is no loading in reality and it's just an animation, use Javascript.

Comment: Yeah, and that's what I've been getting. I'm not closed to JS, I just wanted to know if there was a way in PHP.

Comment: ANswer to that is: yes (see my edit), ubt it involves JS, too, plus you shouldn't do it.

Answer (score 0):

PHP can't do this for you because it is all server-side code. You have to use something on the client to get this to work. If you want to use SUPER simple JavaScript, you could do the following (but know that this is very ugly and shouldn't be used as an example for "real" work):

```
<div id="progress-bar">
<script type="text/javascript">
  var progressBerElement = document.getElementById('progress-bar');
  var currentWidth = -1;
  var INTERVAL = 3 * 1000 / 100; // 3 seconds with 100 updates = 30ms between updates
  function updateWidth() {
    progressBarElement.style.width = ++currentWidth + '%';
    if (currentWidth < 100) {
      setTimeout(updateWidth, INTERVAL);
    }
  }
  setTimeout(updateWidth, INTERVAL);
</script>
```

This could also be accomplished with some CSS3 magic (which I don't know).

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS 3 animations. (polyfills are available for old-IE) http://jsfiddle.net/dLEFG/1/

```
<div style="animation: myAnimation 1s;"></div>
```

and

```
@keyframes myAnimation {
    from {
        width: 0%;
    }
    to {
        width: 100%;
    }
}
```

Of course, you should provide vendor prefixes (like in the fiddle).